Node::Advertise(): Error advertising topic [/theBot/joint_cmd]. Did you forget to start the discovery service?
I am very new to gazebo. as of now I am trying to integrate ROS2 humble + URDF + gazebo but I keep getting this error message whenever I try to move the model in gazebo
[gzclient -2] Node::Advertise(): Error advertising topic [/my_bot/joint_cmd]. Did you forget to start the discovery service?

I do have the ros2 daemon running with my bot's URDF published to the robot_description topic, the log looks like this:
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713077551.158830463] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713077551.159119912] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713077551.159133469] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_sensor1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713077551.159139962] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_sensor2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713077551.159146907] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment ir_sensor3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713077551.159152365] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713077551.159158132] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment lidar_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713077551.159167377] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel

It works on Rviz2, and even joint_state_publisher_gui works fine by subscribing to the robot_description topic. However Gazebo can detect the model, but cannot read it, it shows no links or joints.
Any help would be highly appreciated. I am using - Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2
Please let me know if you need any further details.
I don't know if this is important, but when every time I run Gazebo, I also get this log:
[gzclient-2] libcurl: (6) Could not resolve host: fuel.ignitionrobotics.org

